# multiplication of specific column in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, python-responses

I have two data frames namely shares and Log_Returns. I want to multiply first digit of shares with 1st column of Log_Returns. 2nd digit of shares with 2nd column and so on.

I have tried for loop but getting no output and I have got error too.

I have tried this code but no output was there

```
shares
Out[34]: 
           0
0 -10.466597
1  92.589647
2  17.876951

Log_Return
Out[35]: 
                 UBL      WAHN       SCL
Date                                    
2018-12-26 -0.016651  0.000000  0.000000
2018-12-27 -0.022567 -0.014917  0.045282
2018-12-28 -0.034484  0.000000  0.000000
2018-12-31 -0.044806  0.000000 -0.048742


i=0
        for j in range(Log_Return.shape[1]):
#j chooses the column of Log data frame
#shape[1] gives number of columns
        for k in range(len(Log_Return)):
# k chooses the rows one by one of jth column

             shares.iloc[i,0]*Log_Return.iloc[j,k]
#you can multiply and even store the values or do any operations you want 
        i+=1
#i determines the row of shares data frame
```

but I get this error

```
File "<ipython-input-36-ea1f8caa95e5>", line 2
    for j in range(Log_Return.shape[1]):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Remove trailing spaces before the `for` keyword.

Comment: The error occurs because you have an indented `for` block that shouldn't be indented. @botchniaque, it's a nitpick, but trailing spaces are spaces _after_ something. _Leading_ spaces are before the thing

Answer (score 0):

Indent properly, so the interpreter knows you have nested loops.
Also, you probably want to `print` out the products.

```
        for j in range(Log_Return.shape[1]):
            i = j
            for k in range(len(Log_Return)):
                print(shares.iloc[i, 0] * Log_Return.iloc[j, k])
```